# C# Plugin to open web browser (How to add an option to open specific website)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, plugins, add-in

I asked this already but got no response.
I have a plugin that opens internet explorer when clicked.
I want to make it so that you can right click it or even go into some options menu, and change the default site loaded and have it save.
The user won't have access to the source code to change the website that is opened so how can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

if you spawn process, use commandline paramters like iexplore.exe www.hotmail.com
if you have programmatic access, you could use something like webBrowser.Navigate("www.hotmail.com")

Comment: I know how to make the browser open a site. I need to know how to let the user specify the website so when the browser opens it will open that site all of the time. For example, in the code the standard website is www.facebook.com

But if the user wants the browser to always open to www.google.com how can I make an option to allow them to do that from Visual Studio without getting into the plugins code